# bench marking windows machine -

Tags: windows, performance, performance-monitoring, benchmark

We have a Java based product that is mainly used on windows. Some customers complain that application is slow. We have analysed product using JProfiler and improved various bits.

As a next step, it will be useful run some "benchmark"  tools on individual machines. Is there free/open source tool available for windows?

edit:  I am looking for a tool to benchmark and compare two different machines- Not my application. Title is misleading. I removed java from it

Comment: What do you want to benchmark? CPU, network, disk? Is your application memory-bound, CPU-bound, IO-bound?

Answer (score 1):

JDK 1.6 comes with [VisualVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html) , this is simple to use for profiling.

Some other [Open source profilers are listed](http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers) here.

I have used [Perf4J](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/) in the past to measure time taken on various code modules (like UI or DAO calls etc) , otherwise [InfraRED](http://infrared.sf.net/) is also recommended.